# WEB API 2 Application_Start() firing on dev but not when i deploy on iis server

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2, asp.net-web-api-routing

i didn't find solution over the web so i'm trying here, i really don't know what the problem is but i use .NET 4.5 application pool (not the classic)
i always get 404 error when it needs to get to one of the controllers
i tried to print out when it get to the Global file - but it seems that its not even get there.

```
<configuration>
 <configSections>
<section name="log4net"   type="log4net.Config.Log4NetConfigurationSectionHandler, log4net"/>
</configSections>
<log4net>
<root>
  <level value="INFO"/>
  <appender-ref ref="RollingFileAppender"/>
  <appender-ref ref="ConsoleAppender"/>
</root>
<appender name="RollingFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
  <file value="c:\ApplicationLogs\CenterInterface\mylogfile.txt"/>
  <appendToFile value="true"/>
  <rollingStyle value="Size"/>
  <maxSizeRollBackups value="5"/>
  <maximumFileSize value="10MB"/>
  <staticLogFileName value="true"/>
  <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
    <conversionPattern value="%date{dd/MM/yy HH:mm:ss}  [%thread] %level %logger - %message%newline"/>
  </layout>
</appender>
<appender name="ConsoleAppender" type="log4net.Appender.ConsoleAppender">
  <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
    <conversionPattern value="%date{ABSOLUTE}      [%thread] %level %logger - %message%newline"/>
  </layout>
  <filter type="log4net.Filter.StringMatchFilter">
    <stringToMatch value="test"/>
  </filter>
  <filter type="log4net.Filter.DenyAllFilter"/>
  </appender>
  <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
  <conversionPattern value="%date [%thread] %-5level %logger [%ndc]      - %message%newline"/>
  </layout>
 </log4net>

<appSettings>
<!--<add key="DBpackage" value="TESTMOSH." />-->
<add key="DBpackage" value="PCK_DN_VER1."/>
<add key="AuthTokenExpiry" value="900"/>
</appSettings>

<system.web>
<compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5.2"/>
<httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5"/>
</system.web>
<system.webServer>

<staticContent>
  <remove fileExtension=".woff"/>
  <remove fileExtension=".woff2"/>
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".woff" mimeType="application/font-woff"/>
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".woff2" mimeType="application/font-woff2"/>
</staticContent>
  <handlers>
  <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0"/>
  <remove name="OPTIONSVerbHandler"/>
  <remove name="TRACEVerbHandler"/>
  <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="*" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0"/>
  </handlers>
 </system.webServer>

</configuration>


public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        /*SystemDiagnosticsTraceWriter traceWriter = config.EnableSystemDiagnosticsTracing();
        traceWriter.IsVerbose = false;
        traceWriter.MinimumLevel = TraceLevel.Info;*/
        //traceWriter.FormatDateTime(new DateTime().ToUniversalTime());



        // Web API configuration and services

        // Web API routes
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
```

and i'm trying to do first this:

```
$http.post('/api/Authenticate/', { username: username, password: password })
            .success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                $http.defaults.headers.common['Token'] = headers().token;
                $http.defaults.headers.common['tokenexpiry'] = headers().tokenexpiry;
                $rootScope.globals.currentUser.group = headers().groupname;
                $http.defaults.headers.common.Authorization = 'Token ' + headers().token;
                callback(data);
            })
            .error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                callback(status);
            });

    };
```

Comment: can you also show us your controller file and WebApiConfig.cs file, and let us know what is the link you are using to access the API on which you are getting 404

Answer (score 0, accepted):

seems that the issue wasn't that as my index page was loading, i don't know why i thought that the issue was there? :)
anyway the problem was with the oracle.dataaccess dll file - i debugged it more carefully.